# Collision bounds for 2D Sprites in the Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, physics, image, collision

How can I make Collision bounds for 2D sprites in the BGE? (The 2D sprite I am trying to make collision bounds for is the image I attached below).

I imported the 2D sprites as planes with the "Import images as planes" add on (I checked "use alpha" when importing the image) but I do not how to make collision bounds for it.

I am also gonna be using "Character" physics for the 2D sprite.

> I am also new to the Blender Game Engine, so please try to explain it
>   as good as possible.

[image: This is the 2D sprite I want to make collision bounds for.]

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic and physics settings on a different object, and parent your image plane to that object. Set your image plane as "no collision," and your other object's physics to "character." You can edit the collision bounds and other physics settings until you are happy with the result.

This is a setup I use commonly for making projectiles:

[image]

Here, I have a no collision plane parented to the collision object, but I am using rigid body physics instead of character physics on that actual physics object. - This would work in your case as well, just use character physics.